# Why am I unable to boot from second hard drive (with Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, multi-boot

I installed Ubuntu on my second hard drive with Windows on my first drive. However, I'm not able to boot into Ubuntu. I tried to change the drive order in my BIOS and it still skipped straight into Windows. Also when I tried to manually select a drive to boot from, it only showed me the option of Windows Boot from my first hard drive.

This is in UEFI mode. What can be causing this not to recognize I have an Ubuntu install to boot from?

Comment: laptop is an acer aspire e15

Comment: Did you install ubuntu in UEFI mode? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: This confuses me. Is there a basic summary of steps to use? Seems like the system should automatically detect that my install is EFI.